# accessing function javascript

Tags: javascript, function, namespaces

How can I access the function from other namespace?

Eg:

```
FavoriteFlavor.instructState.prototype = { 
    test: function() {
      // call function show from chooseEmoticonState
      // I have tried calling FavoriteFlavor.chooseEmoticonState.show();
    }
}

FavoriteFlavor.chooseEmoticonState.prototype = {
    show: function() {
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have to code with `prototype` or are you allow to use a different pattern of javascript??

Comment: Since prototypes are meant to be methods that are given to newly created objects (not to be used as namespaces), whenever someone is regularly looking to call methods on the prototype directly rather than call them on an instantiated object, it makes me wonder if your functions are laid out properly and should be in an actual namespace and not on a prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `show` function is on `FavoriteFlavor.chooseEmoticonState.prototype`, not `FavoriteFlavor.chooseEmoticonState`, so you *could* call it with:

```
FavoriteFlavor.chooseEmoticonState.prototype.show();
```

But given that it's on a prototype, it doesn't really make a lot of sense to call it directly.

What would make sense is to call it on an instance of `chooseEmoticonState`:

```
// assume chooseState has been instantiated with 
//    new FavoriteFlavor.chooseEmoticonState();
chooseState.show();
```

Or if `show()` isn't intended to be an instance method, put it directly on `FavoriteFlavor.chooseEmoticonState`:

```
FavoriteFlavor.chooseEmoticonState = {
    show: function() {
    }
};
```

and *then* you can call it in the fashion you were trying to before:

```
FavoriteFlavor.choseEmoticonState.show();
```

Comment: you are right! Thanks you for explaining.
Can you please simplified about prototype pattern? I'm a bit confusing about that.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to call the method directly from the `prototype` object:

```
FavoriteFlavor.chooseEmoticonState.prototype.show();
```

However, any `this` instance references would not point to an instance of `instructState`. You can correct this by using the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method, and passing `this` as the first parameter.

```
FavoriteFlavor.chooseEmoticonState.prototype.show.call(this);
```

Also, unless you have a reason not to, you could simple add the `show` method of the `chooseEmoticonState` prototype to the `instructState` prototype.

```
FavoriteFlavor.instructState.prototype.show = FavoriteFlavor.chooseEmoticonState.prototype.show;
```

Answer (score 1):

in a different javascript pattern: (just for the sake of diversity)

http://jsfiddle.net/za6muccw/

```
FavoriteFlavor = {};

FavoriteFlavor.chooseEmoticonState = (function(){
         //private
    var myprivate = "im private";

    function show(){
        alert("goo")
    }

    return {
        show : show //its making me public
    }
})();

FavoriteFlavor.instructState = (function(){
   //private
   var myprivate = "im private";
   FavoriteFlavor.chooseEmoticonState.show();
})();
```

Comment: Still trying to work out the point of a private variable that isn't accessed by anything. The second IIFE doesn't return anything, so the value of *FavoriteFlavor.instructState* will be *undefined*.

Comment: its just to make an example of private variable,this pattern name is anonymous function, which allow to create public and private variable, in the second "object class" there is not any return since you are not publishing nothing and in the first one you are returning show which its a reference to the `function show()` you are making it public, now `FavoriteFlavor.chooseEmoticonState.show` its public